# Access sqlite database of plugin from native

Tags: android, objective-c, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I am developing an ionic app, and it have several native parts

I am using this plugin, for local databases

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

I have no problem in creating or accessing it from the hybrid part, with functions like this:

```
 var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({
          name: "dbApplication.sqlite",
          path: 'documents/',
          environment: "SQLITE_ENV_MOBILE",
          bgType: 1
        });

        db.transaction(function (tx) {

          tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO main.table ( name, email, sfid ) VALUES (?,?,?)", [user.name, user.email, user.sfid], function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          }, errorCallback);

        }, errorCallback);
```

But i am trying to access it from the android native part, with this code:

```
    private static String DB_PATH = "documents/";
    private static String DB_NAME ="dbApplication.sqlite";// Database name

public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }

    public HashMap getDataSigner(Integer signerId) {
        openDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBase;
        //"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main.signers (idSigner INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT, idNumber TEXT, rol TEXT)"

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT name, idNumber FROM signers WHERE idSigner="+signerId+"", null);
        HashMap signer = new HashMap();
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            signer.put("name", c.getString(0));
            signer.put("idNumber", c.getString(1));

        }
        return signer;
    }
```

It returns the following error:

```
    Failed to open database 'documents/dbApplication.sqlite'.
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error(Sqlite code 14): Could not open database,(OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
```

So my question is: What is the correct path to the databases, in android, for the databases created with the sqlite plugin?

I have also try to dig in the plugin code, but I dont understand it well, as I am not a good android programmer

Also, if someone have the way to access it from IOS native, it would be awesome, as I am going to need it later

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer to myself

The correct Path, in Android is:

```
mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(this.cordova.getActivity().getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

Also, remember to close conections before use, if not, you couldn't use it

Comment: I want to do same thing also but my plugin application is crashed when I call getData function.